# how to handle a php script same way with browser and command line

Tags: php

my problem is to create a simple php script that I want to call with params from command line or browser:

```
if(!empty($_GET)) {
    $parameters = $_GET;
} else if(isset($argv)) {
    $parameters = $argv;
}
var_dump($parameters);
```

this gives different result :

in browser : **http://localhost/test/script.php?test=123**

```
array(1) { ["test"]=> string(3) "123" }
```

in shell : **php script.php test=123**

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "script.php"
  [1]=>
    string(8) "test=123"
}
```

I want to call the params by their names.

Comment: Look at [argv's documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php) and you will understand why the outputs are different. To generate the same output, you'll need to iterate over argv[1, ...], retrieve the different parameters, cut them on the operator '=' and insert the left operand as a key and the right operand as the value of this key in an associative array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using [getopt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getopt.php) (or getlongopt) (see same manual link)

`array getopt ( string $options [, array $longopts ] )`

Answer (score 2):

The idiomatic syntax for the command line is:

```
program -o val --opt value pos_value
```

Such syntax can be parsed in PHP using [`getopt`](http://php.net/getopt).

> ```
> $options = getopt("f:hp:");
> var_dump($options);
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The `argv` parameter's first element will always be the name of the script that has been executed. You can simply ignore that first argument and start from index `1`.

Taken from the [relevant documentation:](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php)

> Note: The first argument `$argv[0]` is always the name that was used to run the script.

As others have mentioned, you can also use the [`getopt` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getopt.php) that is specifically used to extract options, their names, and their valies from a CLI. The `argv` variable simply holds a list of arguments that were passed. Since the actual program that is being executed is the PHP interpreter, even the script name is an argument.

```
php my_script.php another_arg more_args
//  ^ argv[0].....^ argv[1]...^ argv[2]
```

---

As a side note, this behavior of `argv` including the executing script file is consistent across other platforms/technologies. For example, the same behavior can be seen with [python](/questions/tagged/python), [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) and many many more.

General explanation taken from [this page](http://jnoconor.github.io/blog/2013/10/13/a-short-explanation-of-argv/)

> **What is ARGV?**
>   As a concept, ARGV is a convention in programming that goes back (at least) to the C language. It refers to the “argument vector,” which is basically a variable that contains the arguments passed to a program through the command line. It typically manifests as an array and can be manipulated in that way, meaning you can reference specific arguments by index or you can iterate through them in the standard ways.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to pass all parameters via the CLI in query string format (e.g. `test=123&var=me`) take a look at [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php).

```
if(!empty($_GET)) {
    $parameters = $_GET;
} else if(!empty($argv[1])) {
    $parameters = parse_str($argv[1]);
}
```

If there are separated, then **deceze** has [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31701092/164998).

Answer (score 1):

I found that I cann call my script with php-cgi instead of php;
CLI : php-cgi script.php test=123
and 
Browser : http://localhost/test/script.php?test=123
give the same result that I want.
Thank you all